# iOS app - size of the app is too big after install SDK from POD

Tags: ios, optimization, ipa, app-thinning

I want to add an **80 MB** framework to my iOS App that is currently about **30 MB**. Will the size of my app be **110 MB**?

Comment: You would have to build the app to find out.  Chances are that you won't end up distributing all 80MB of the SDK.

Comment: Even if you build it you will get the real size only when you upload to app store. Mainly if you are using bitcode. It reduces significantly the app size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:**
You'll have to add the SDK and compile the code to see what *your* resulting size is.

**Details:**
When you build an app, the compiler rewrites it into machine-readable code, doing some further magic to optimize the end result. Because of this, the size of your code files, including SDK files, has no relationship whatsoever to the completed app executable's size.

For one example, your code may have tons of comments in it. However, the compiler wouldn't even look at those comments when producing the final app.

Additionally, an app compiled for `debug` will be larger than the same app compiled for `release`. That's because the compiler will leave some things in the `debug` version for troubleshooting that it does *not* include in a final `release` version.

As noted in some of the comments, when you submit your code to the Store, it may be further "trimmed", possibly ending up with an even smaller size. (In very simple terms, Apple has found a way to share common base code between apps on a device. The common code is removed from apps submitted to the store, since the apps can use that central base code instead. This results in smaller, faster apps.)

There are various things you can do to optimize an app into the smallest possible footprint, just as there are ways you can optimize an app to be faster or more responsive. Doing so, though, is totally dependent on the tools you're using, the statements you use, the way you import items, etc. You would have to consider these items individually. (For example, are you using the best structure for a task - array?, dictionary?, set? Are you using the most efficient method to perform a task? There's this whole "[Big-O](https://www.google.com/search?q=big%20o%20optimization)" thing... ;)